# Btrfs: available space not used after migrating from RAID1 to RAID6

Tags: raid, btrfs, software-raid

I had 8 2TB disks running in a RAID1 setup but it started to get full so I converted it to a RAID6. However, it seems I can't use the space I've gained by switching to RAID6.

My filesystem is pretty full:

```
# btrfs fi df /mnt/r6
Data, RAID6: total=6.54TiB, used=6.39TiB
System, RAID6: total=96.00MiB, used=688.00KiB
Metadata, RAID6: total=9.89GiB, used=8.72GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

Can't resize:

```
# sudo btrfs fi resize +1g /mnt/r6
Resize '/mnt/r6' of '+1g'
ERROR: unable to resize '/mnt/r6': no enough free space
```

And the disks are only half-used:

```
# sudo btrfs fi show
Total devices 8 FS bytes used 6.40TiB
devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk1
devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk2
devid    3 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk3
devid    4 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk4
devid    5 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk5
devid    6 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk6
devid    7 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk7
devid    8 size 1.82TiB used 1.09TiB path /dev/mapper/disk8
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

None of these outputs indicate that the filesystem is full.

The output of `btrfs fi df /mnt/r6` seems fine. The first line:

```
Data, RAID6: total=6.54TiB, used=6.39TiB
```

Indicates that 6.54 TiB have been allocated for data, and 6.39 TiB of those have been actually used. It does *not* mean that you only have 6.54 TiB - 6.39 TiB = 0.15 TiB of space left. You should have about `1.82 * (8 - 2) TiB = 10.92 TiB` of total space available for data and metadata, which means that you have about `10.92 TiB - 6.39 TiB = 4.53 TiB` free space (discounting the negligible amount of metadata being used).

The output of `btrfs fi show` is indicating that all of the drives are equally utilized and that there is plenty of space left.

The `btrfs filesystem usage` command gives a much nicer overview of how much space is used (and how much remains available), but sadly it does not yet support RAID6 mode.

Still, the output of plain old `df` should also indicate that you have plenty of space remaining, though it may be somewhat off. But if `df` is telling you that you have several TiB free, then you are no where near full.

The resize operation is presumably failing because btrfs has already been given the full drives to work with, so there is no room to expand to.